# Change the View on button Click in WPF MVVM Pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view

I have 3 buttons on one usercontrol (usercontrol1.xaml) in the Window . Now on-click of button 1 ,I want to switch the view to another usercontrol (usercontrol2.xaml), which again have 3 buttons and so on.

How to implement in MVVM Pattern in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that im using caliburn micro for this example

```
 private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator => IoC.Get<IEventAggregator>(key: nameof(EventAggregator));
        private IWindowManager _windowManager => IoC.Get<IWindowManager>(key: nameof(WindowManager));
        public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
        }


        public string _firstName;
        // public ShellViewModel page = new ShellViewModel();
        public string FirstName
        {
            get {       
                return _firstName;
            }
            set
            {

                _firstName = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FirstName);

            }
        }
        public ICommand ConvertTextCommand
        {
            get { return new DelegateCommand(ConvertText); }
        }

        void ConvertText()
        {
            //string url = "https://www.google.com/";
            string url = FirstName;
             string result;
             using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
             {
                 using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
                 {
                     using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                     {
                          result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                     }
                 }
             }
             //(MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).txtForm1TextBox.Text = "Some text";
             //Application.Current.Resources.Add("PageSource", result);
             // NavigationService.NavigateToViewModel<SecondViewModel>("Hello");
             _windowManager.ShowWindow(new PageSourceViewModel(_eventAggregator), null);
             _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(result);

        }
```

You can check caliburn micro and see that you can just create a new view model in a window manager instance

here is also 2 links to 2 tutorials that helped me solve this issue for MVVM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laPFq3Fhs8k

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kGcE9thwNw&list=LLy8ROdSzpPJnikdZQ1XPZkQ&index=30&t=0s

the first tutorial will help you to get a general idea. The second will help you with events and you can look back to my code and see how i handled a new window instance.

You can also call the same view model for a new instance of the same window like you said in the question

You will also need to make a boostrapper class. For my example i did it like this.

```
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {

        private readonly SimpleContainer _container =
            new SimpleContainer();
        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            _container.Instance<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
            _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
            _container.PerRequest<ShellViewModel>();
        }
        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {

            _container.Instance<SimpleContainer>(_container);

            _container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>(key: nameof(WindowManager))
                .Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>(key: nameof(EventAggregator));
            DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();



        }


        protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
        {
            return _container.GetInstance(service, key);
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
        {
            return _container.GetAllInstances(service);
        }

        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            _container.BuildUp(instance);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer . But I want to implement this , without any third party framework .

Comment: Im not capable to provide code ATM but i can give some hints that you can make a simple window ``` Window window = new window ``` and there is a parameter to give context. so you can give your viewModel. Also you would need to route the view models with views respectively so the context would be shown correctly.